# In VBA, how can I refresh one pivot table for each external data source in the active workbook?

Tags: vba, refresh, pivot-table

So I'm trying to work out the best way to refresh just one pivot table for each external data table in the active workbook (because once you refresh one, the rest automatically refresh)

The number of data tables will vary between different workbooks that the macro opens so it needs to allow for this.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the `ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches` collection and call `.Refresh` on each member of the collection.